# Why should we serialize data before sending in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, serialization

I want to know why we need to serialize a JavaScript Object before sending to the server.

Example:

```
var send_data= {
    id : 10,
    name : 20,

    school : {
       name : "xyz",
       location : "some place"
    }
}
```

If I send this data without serializing, using ajax like this

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "some.php",
    data: { "info" : send_data}
})
```

Is there something wrong with this code? Because I can access all the data without unserializing...

```
$data = $_POST["info"];
echo $data["school"]["name"];
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the way you're sending it in the example.

Comment: Use `JSON.Stringify` if you are sending data to Server and if you are getting data from Server use `JSON.Parse`

Comment: @ArpitSrivastava: Not necessary. The `data` parameter the OP uses works just fine.

Comment: @Cerbrus:But it's a good practice we should use in order to check weather we are right dict or JSON to server because the way user handling post data.

Comment: @ArpitSrivastava: You know jQuery serializes the data parameter, internally, right? And what are you talking about the weather for?

Comment: @Cerbrus: I know jQuery serialize the data parameter, I am talking in general if you are using Javascript

Comment: thanks a lot guys.. Didn't knew that jQuery does it automatically...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data MUST be serialized, because network traffic consists of series of bytes. At some point, your data structures must be turned into something that can be sent over a network.

However, jQuery's `.ajax()` function *already* does serialization if you use an object instead of a string for its data argument. So no need to do it there.

I don't know PHP well but if the code you have there works, then apparently PHP also automatically unserializes the data.

So I'd say that yes, serializing is necessary, but doing it the way you describe actually does serialize it in the background.

Comment: Thanks a lot Remco.
I was so confused that I started to think, that browser is serializing that for me... and then I started to think about cross browser compatibility..

Thanks a lot :)